# Please, delete my question regarding svchost.exe

Tags: support, specific-question, delete

I have a question about my Super User post: [How to force svchost.exe to run as a single process (Windows 10)](https://superuser.com/questions/1834771/how-to-force-svchost-exe-to-run-as-a-single-process-windows-10)

I want to delete my question, but I'm unable to delete it because someone wrote an "answer" that doesn't make any attempt to answer what I asked. They simply copied and pasted the information I posted in the question as a link.

This is obviously useless, since I already know what I posted, and it doesn't offer any solutions to the question.  The answer neither adds anything useful and seems rather condescending and disrespectful, simply telling me to "close apps."

Please, delete the question.

Answer (score 3):

In most cases we'd be disinclined to delete a question - and if memory serves, you can't delete your own question if there's an [*upvoted* answer.](https://superuser.com/help/deleted-questions)

A couple of observations.

- if a large part of an answer is from other sources, quoted verbatim, its plagiarism. If its quoted from something in a question, *clearly* explanation is needed for OP
- there's no real point arguing with someone over an answer that's not up to scratch. Just downvote it
- If a question is properly difficult, sometimes the first answers might not be great, patience is good.

If you flag your question, or request on meta, and its reasonable, we might be inclined to acquiesce to a request for deletion, but you never know without asking.